# document.on click fires automatically when page loads

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I load the page, `document.on('click',...)` requests get sent instantaneously regardless of the condition

Example:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var poll = new Poll();

  if($('.loadPoll')[0]){ //this works fine
    poll.loadPoll(function(){
        console.log("loaded poll successful");

    });
  } 

 $(document).on('click', '#SubmitVote', poll.afterSubmit(function(){
        console.log("Poll has been voted on!");
    })); //this gets sent regardless of clicks


});
```

Even if there is no element with `SubmitVote` as an ID it gets sent automatically

EDIT:

changed to:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
   var poll = new Poll();

    if($('.loadPoll')[0]){
      poll.loadPoll(function(){
        console.log("loaded poll successful");

     });
    }
    $(document).on('click', 'button.SubmitVote', function(){
        poll.afterSubmit(function(){
            console.log("Poll has been voted on!");
            });
        });
}
```

Comment: `poll.afterSubmit(function(){...})` executes `afterSubmit` immediately and the return value will be set as event handler. This is probably not what you want, but it depends on what `afterSubmit` does.

Comment: Thanks, Felix. If you put that as an answer I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Felix Kling correctly identified the issue in his/her comment, but I'll expand a bit further - your code is executing a function (`poll.afterSubmit`) and assigning the result of that function call as the click handler.  Unless that function *returns a function*, this probably isn't what you want.

```
$(document).on('click', '#SubmitVote', function(){
    console.log("Poll has been voted on!");
});
```

The above strips out the `poll.afterSubmit()` call and simply assigns the handler function.  This may or may not be sufficient to meet your needs, it's not clear from your question exactly what you're attepting with `poll.afterSubmit`.